# Google Sheets - Change data in a sheet depending on what cell is clicked

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a "Main page" in my spreadsheet that allows you to search for chemicals and returns some information on any match found within the source data. I want each result to have a link that the user can click that will open up a sheet with some more detailed information on the particular chemical clicked. Is this possible?

[Example - clicking F5 would link to another sheet that would fill in cell A1 with "Carbon Monoxide" but clicking F6 would instead fill in the cell with "Nickel Carbonate"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN1Qa.png)

Comment: If you right click on a cell you can get the link. You can use that to extend your filter.

Answer (score 0):

You should first make a list of all search items along with the links of the desired page, then in column G use vlookup to get the link based on the name from column C.

Now in column F use the Hyperlink function to generate a clickable link say

```
=HYPERLINK(G5,"See More")
```

Can use `arrayformula` for entire range.

Comment: I may be able to make something work using that method, but ideally I want a single sheet labelled "Detailed info" that each result will link to and pre-populate with its own details, rather than each entry having its own "details page" as that will mean having several hundred extra sheets.

Comment: In the approach which I suggested you need only one sheet for table of item names with corresponding links where you want to navigate.  Your main sheet will fetch data from this sheet using vlookup.

Comment: From what I understand you're saying to have a list of links in the original data sheet that take you to a page with more details on each result, however I want all the links to go to the same page in the spreadsheet, but loading different information. So I need the hyperlink to automatically fill in a cell on the "details page" when it is clicked, this is the part I'm struggling with